# How to display the json response in angular2

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to display the console JSON response to the html. The response looks like `{Response: "Mobile number is not registered"}` . How to display the "Mobile number is not registered" alone in html.I am using angular2.

```
 OnSendOTP(loginIntData : LoginInterface) {

        console.log("inside send otp services");
        let data = {
                  "userName":loginIntData.mobile
                  }
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        let head = new Headers({
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  });


        this.http.post('url', body, {headers : head}).map(res =>  res.json()).subscribe(

          data => {
             this.data = data;
            },


                    () => {console.log("send the OTP to the registered mobile" , this.loginIntData)}, //For Success Response
                  );   


  }
```

Comment: Issue resolved by using the split function

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be calling some api's for mobile number verification

**Component Side :**

```
data = {};

this.http.get('your_url').subscribe(data => {
   this.data = data;
});
```

**Template Side :**

```
{{ data.Response }}
```

Comment: yes, i am calling api from the service and from the backend i am getting the response in json format, {
    "Response": "Mobile number is not registered"
} like this . I am able to display the complete json response in the view. But i need to display only the second data which is Mobile number is not registered

Comment: I thin you need to convert response to json `data= data.toJSON()`;

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know what you tried. But the concept is, you could use scope object to bind the component values into html

```
export class MaintainCOCComponent {
message:string="";

  ngOnInit()
  {
   this.message=Response;// binding service response to the object
  }
}
```

anso you should initialize your html file with your componenet like,

```
 @Component({
        templateUrl: './sample.component.html'
    })
```

Then you can call that object inside of your html. like,

```
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**in file.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'file.component.html'
})
export class AroundmeComponent implements OnInit {
    results: Observable<any>;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        http.get('url').subscribe((res) => this.results = res.json());
    }
   ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

**In View**

```
<!-- file.component.html -->

{{results | json}}
```

Comment: don't forget to add HttpModule in your app.module.ts file

Comment: Paste your json response here.

Comment: {Response: "Mobile number is not registered"}

Comment: just use this {{results.Response}}

Comment: Sorry! can't help you without looking at the code now. If possible please share your code.